How to handle unstructured JSON data in R?
If we have such a not structured data, whose key includes information and coupling with another key-value. Does anyone have good idea to handle it in R? Since R only have structured object data.frame structure.
{"data":[{"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"}, {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"}, {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"}, {"Manitoba":"MB","MB":"1.28"}, {"Saskatchewan":"SK","SK":"1.1"}]}
Expect it be converted as a structured data frame.

In the call to jsonlite::fromJSON(...) add "simplifyVector = FALSE" so that the data is returned as a list.
